# Open TabItem in a new Window

Tags: c#, wpf, attached-properties

In my application I have the following attached-property to call an `ICommand` when a `UserControl` or `Window` is loaded:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LoadedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "LoadedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(UserControlExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnLoadedCommandChanged));

private static void OnLoadedCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentControl userControl = d as ContentControl;
    if (userControl == null)
        return;

    if (e.NewValue is ICommand)
    {
        userControl.Loaded += UserControlOnLoaded;
    }
}

private static void UserControlOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentControl userControl = sender as ContentControl;
    if (userControl == null)
        return;

    ICommand command = GetLoadedCommand(userControl);
    command.Execute(GetLoadedCommandParameter(userControl));
}

public static void SetLoadedCommand(DependencyObject element, ICommand value)
{
    element.SetValue(LoadedCommandProperty, value);
}

public static ICommand GetLoadedCommand(DependencyObject element)
{
    return (ICommand) element.GetValue(LoadedCommandProperty);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty LoadedCommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "LoadedCommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(UserControlExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

public static void SetLoadedCommandParameter(DependencyObject element, object value)
{
    element.SetValue(LoadedCommandParameterProperty, value);
}

public static object GetLoadedCommandParameter(DependencyObject element)
{
    return (object) element.GetValue(LoadedCommandParameterProperty);
}
```

This just works fine. In my views I call this on a `UserControl` like:

```
AttachedProperties:UserControlExtensions.LoadedCommand="{Binding ViewLoadedCommand}"
```

And the `ICommand` in the viewmodel will be called.

Now I've implemented a feature that I can click on a `Button` in the header of a `TabItem` and open the content of this `TabItem` in a new Window. (Like undocking a Tab in the visual studio).

Therefor I'm using the following code:

```
private void OpenInWindowButtonOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button == null)
        return;

    TabItem tabItem = button.Tag as TabItem;
    if (tabItem == null)
        return;

    string title = string.Empty;

    ContentControl headerContent = tabItem.Header as ContentControl;
    if (headerContent != null)
    {
        title = headerContent.Content.ToString();
    }

    string workspaceId = tabItem.Tag as string;

    TabItem workspaceTab = WorkspaceTab.Items.OfType<TabItem>()
        .FirstOrDefault(ti => ti.Tag is string && (string)ti.Tag == workspaceId);
    if (workspaceTab != null)
    {
        WorkspaceWindow workspaceWindow = new WorkspaceWindow(tabItem);
        workspaceWindow.Content = workspaceTab.Content;

        workspaceWindow.Width = (workspaceTab.Content as FrameworkElement).ActualWidth;
        workspaceWindow.Height = (workspaceTab.Content as FrameworkElement).ActualHeight;

        workspaceWindow.Title = title;
        workspaceWindow.Closing += WorkspaceWindowOnClosing;
        workspaceWindow.Show();
        workspaceWindows.Add(workspaceId, workspaceWindow);
        WorkspaceTab.Items.Remove(workspaceTab);
    }
}
```

This also just works fine.

My problem now is if I open a new tab (witch contains also a `TabControl` where the `TabItem`s have the loaded-attachedproperty) and move this tab to a new window with the code above: The loaded-command will not called when I switch to the view where the loaded-attachedproperty is used.

If I debug the attachedproperty I can see, that the OnLoadedCommandChanged is called correctly but the UserControlOnLoaded is not called. If I don't open the `TabItem` in a new Window the UserControlOnLoaded is called correctly.

Any ideas why the loaded-event of subpages don't get fired if I move a `TabItem` to a new `Window`?

Comment: I can't see anything with a DataContext, but are you sure that it is not changed with a new Window ?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I thing I've found the problem. The line `WorkspaceTab.Items.Remove(workspaceTab);` removes the tab from the tabcontrol. I seems that the remove also do a cleanup of all events

Answer (score 0):

The problem was within the line `WorkspaceTab.Items.Remove(workspaceTab);`

This line removes the `TabItem` from the `TabControl` and it seems that wpf does here some kind of cleanup.

I've solved the problem be just setting the `Visibility` of the `TabItem` to Hidden.